# How to use ng-filter Json [@attributes] using Angularjs?

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm trying to filter sports feed by using sports id. but json feeds are @attribute based feed.

**Json feeds**

```
series: [
{
  @attributes: {
   id: "cdf590b4-0206-45b0-9122-20eae46a2b27",
   name: "Pakistan tour of Sri Lanka, 2015",
   year: "2015"
  },
  match: [
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {}
 ],
 comment: []
},
{
 @attributes: {
  id: "324e971e-2044-4fa6-bdb2-0c47c99da64e",
  name: "South Africa tour of Bangladesh, 2015",
  year: "2015"
 },
 match: [
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {}
 ],
 comment: []
},
```

**My Controller**

```
--So this my controller code.--
$http.get('http://example.com/cricket.php').then(function(response) {
    $scope.sports = sports;
    $scope.whichsports = $state.params.id;
}
```

**This My View Filter Code**

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="sport in sports | filter: { id : whichsports }">
```

So Please Help Me.!

Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `$scope.sports = sports;` should be instead `$scope.sports = response;`

And then in the `ng-repeat` you will get the `sport` attributes with `sport['@attributes']`

Comment: Thanks for your Time!  when i use sport['@attributes'] i got error like `Error: [ngRepeat:iidexp] '_item_' in '_item_ in _collection_' should be an identifier or '(_key_, _value_)' expression, but got 'sport['@attributes']'.`